# Запуск метода, который находится в другом .java файле

Tags: java, android, методы

В **OnSwipeTouchListener.java** имеется данный метод:

```
@Override
public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
    System.out.println("DTAP");
    return true;
}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы метод, о котором я писал выше, запускал метод, который находится в **LevelActivity.java**
 Вот он:

```
public void singletap(View view) {
    step++;
    action = "7";
    pStatus = 0;
}
```

Comment: вам нужно реализовать слушатель прямо в активити, как анонимный класс или внутренний класс, тогда он будет иметь доступ к методам активити.

Answer (score 0):

Тут возможно 2 варианта:

1) если возможно сделать **singletap** статичной, то делаем так, а потом просто вызываем следующим образом:

```
@Override
public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
    singletap(view); //вызываем её здесь
    System.out.println("DTAP");
    return true;
}
```

2) вы не можете сделать этот метод статичным. Тогда нужно создать объект класса, которому принадлежит метод **singletap**, а потом уже вызвать.

```
@Override
public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
    LevelActivity la = new LevelActivity(); //ну или какой у вас там конструктор прописан
    la.singletap(view);
    System.out.println("DTAP");
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Подскажи, пожалуйста, что вместо view вводить?

Comment: @Twikoffin у вас в **OnSwipeTouchListener.java** должен быть объект типа View. Его и передавайте. Судя по этим методам, это должна быть какая-то кнопка или что-то типа нее, которая отслеживает таким образом нажатие. P.S.: кнопка наследуется от View, т.е. объекту типа View можно присвоить кнопку.

Comment: в андроид нельзя просто так создать системный компонент (активити), как обычный класс  и думать, что это будет работать. Статики тоже использовать крайне не рекомендуется. Оба ваших решения не подходят для системы андроид

Comment: @pavlofff, спасибо, учту! ;)